# metasearch has_many where all/none has to match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many, sti, meta-search

Im trying to make a metasearch or alternatively a scope that gives me all objects that doesnt have any of its has_many-association equal to type == "Something".

Example:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :billing_base
end

class InvoiceBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end

class Invoice < InvoiceBase
end

class OrderAcknowledgement < InvoiceBase
end
```

Searching for orders that have an invoice is easily done by a custom scope:

```
joins(:invoice_base).where(:invoice_base => {:type => "Invoice"})
```

or metasearch:

```
:invoice_base_type_equals => "Invoice"
```

Now how do I do the opposite, find orders that have NO invoice? (OrderAcknowledgements should always be allowed)

Answer (score 0):

When trying to figure this out on my computer, i ended up writing a sql statement that involves a subquery. I wonder if maybe you can populate the raw SQL into the where method.

```
select * from orders where orders.id not in (SELECT invoice_bases.order_id from invoice_bases);

where("orders.id not in (SELECT invoice_bases.order_id from invoice_bases)")
```

I gave this a try on my site and it seemed to work. Note that I am using MySQL

Comment: That is actually the way I do it right now (with the addition of "where type = 'Invoice'"), but Im not sure if it will be efficient enough considering that the "NOT IN (list of ids)" will be a list of thousands ids.

Comment: Because the invoice bases stores the foreign key value, and you want to find all orders that are not connected to an invoice base, you have to check them all. Think of it like comparing arrays in Ruby. I agree it's not the prettiest thing. But doing it on an indexed column at the database level, will be much faster than comparing it on the software side. Especially when that table gets bigger.

Comment: This does do the trick, but as soon as you have a few thousand records that NOT IN starts to get really expensive.  I feel like there's a better solution out there.